# R keeps bothering me with automatically pop up "Function:data"

Tags: r

Recently R keeps poping up automatically with the Function data, and I have no idea how to fix this problem.
I would be really appreciated if you have any suggestions！

I googled this question but it seems no answer there.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOeyn.jpg)

Comment: If you try to use a dataset called `data` but you didn't define it, R will show the code of the `data()` function which is an existing object.